# Accessible PDF's from Coldfusion 2021

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, accessibility, adobe

I've been looking everywhere, and can't find a suitable answer. We are generating PDF's on the fly for a job board. People click on a job, and have an option to download a PDF version of the job posting. We currently have everything running just fine with cfdocument, but our client is hoping to get the website to 100% compliant with WCAG 2.1.

Currently, i've tried using cfdocument, then using cfPDF to set things like title, as mentioned by Raymond Camden in [ColdFusion 8: Working with PDFs (Part 2)](https://www.raymondcamden.com/2007/07/10/ColdFusion-8-Working-with-PDFs-Part-2) but this doesn't seem to work anymore as the downloaded documents don't keep the set information.

The other issue is the PDF isn't marked as a PDF (apparently a flaw with cfdocument Adobe has no plans to fix).

We've tried cfhtmltopdf, but we require headers and footers for each page, and as many have pointed out on various forums, Adobe's implementation is a joke.

So, my question now is, what is the best route to creating a fully compliant PDF from Coldfusion (3rd party options are a route we are willing to take if needed) Ideally we would want the direct download like CFDocument, but we are not opposed to having a physical file created for each job posting if it means having a compliant PDF.

Our code, after all the body content, looks as follows (again this doesn't set the title, language or tag as PDF, and doesn't allow alt tags on our images for some reason).

```
<cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=filename.pdf">
<cfheader name="Content-Language" value="#session.language.code#" />
<cfdocument name="myPDF" format="pdf" orientation="portrait"  pageType="custom" pageWidth="8.5" pageHeight="10.75" unit="in" localUrl="yes" marginbottom="1.5" margintop="1" marginleft="0.25" marginright="0.25">

***
***
***
***


<cfset PDFinfo=StructNew()> 
<cfset PDFinfo.Title="#returnStruct.JobDetails.title#"> 
<cfset PDFinfo.Language = 'EN-US' />
<CFIF returnStruct.JobDetails.anonymous EQ 0>
    <cfset PDFinfo.Author="#returnStruct.JobDetails.Organization#"> 
<CFELSE>
    <cfset PDFinfo.Author="Employment Agency Name"> 
</CFIF>

<cfpdf action="setInfo" source="myPDF" info="#PDFinfo#">

<cfpdf action="write" source="myPDF" name='myPDF' version="1.4">

<cfcontent type="application/pdf" reset="true" variable="#toBinary(myPDF)#">
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work when trying? This seems fine to me.  The title and author are set when attempting this. The only addition can be the content-disposition in a cfheader tag, that will sort the "not marked as PDF"

Comment: when you run the code above, and scan the PDF via an accessibility scanner, it fails. The title isn't set, no images have alt tags, and the PDF isn't tagged as a PDF. I did miss a line, i had <cfheader name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment;filename=filename.pdf"> just above this but it forgot to copy. If you do a <CFPDF action="getInfo"... right after the "write" command, the title is properly set, but the downloaded document doesn't retain any of this. 

To verify, i use adobe acrobat, and run an accessibility check, which confirms the reports that no title is set

Comment: I've updated my code to show the content-disposition

Comment: What do you mean by "PDF isn't marked as a PDF"? Is that regarding how it is being linked within the HTML versus metadata in the PDF itself? What does your HTML look like? (I use WKHTMLTOPDF and would like to compare results.)

Comment: Currently we are using SortSite Professional to do our primary accessibility scanning. It  comes back with the error "PDFs must be tagged to be accessible by screen readers" for all PDF's rendered via cfdocument. I read somewhere, that Adobe knows about this but has no intentions of fixing it, that people should switch to cfhtmltopdf which will properly tag a PDF file. As mentioned though, their implementation is a joke and doesn't do what we need it to. I was curious about WKhtmlToPDF, but i also say they have accessibility issues they are unwilling to fix.

Comment: you can see the comments on that string here, sorry ran out of comment room.  https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/1605

Comment: So, it is a PDF, but not a well-formed tagged PDF (aka. PDF/UA)? I have not yet found a 100% reliable way to automate the creation of tagged PDF. Most tools completely ignore semantic information. Be sure to report this as a bug under cfPDF

Comment: That is correct brennanyoung, the PDF is generated perfectly, but not being tagged as a PDF for accessibility, and the cfpdf doesn't seem to be setting the title or author meta data when the file is downloaded. cfhtmltopdf DOES tag the file as a pdf, but formatting that is brutal at best. i just tried to log into the adobe community, but apparently adobe can't even keep there own stuff running properly lol Ray Camden did have cfpdf working correctly at one point to set title / author, but as mentioned in the comments this doesn't stick when the file is downloaded (unless syntax has changed?)

Comment: I use SortSite Pro as well. We have some clients that provide PDFs that are image scans... we require them to use Adobe Acrobat to make them accessible. I'm not sure what can be done using CFML and server-side code.